# Angularjs Datatable server side pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I'm trying to make Angularjs Datatable server side pagination in this link https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/serverSideProcessing

So I use this code

```
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
       .withOption('ajax', {
                  dataSrc: function(json) {
                    conole.log(json)
                    json['recordsTotal'] =json.length
                    json['recordsFiltered'] = json.length
                    json['draw']=1
                    conole.log(json)
                    return json;
                  },
              url: 'api/footestrecords',
              type: 'GET'
           })
       .withOption('processing', true)
       .withOption('serverSide', true)
       .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
```

I added recordsTotal, recordsFiltered and row manually in dataSrc parameter

and this is json data before and after add  recordsTotal, recordsFiltered and row

json data before add

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object,
Object,Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object,
Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object,
Object, Object]
```

json data after add

```
 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object,
  Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object,
  Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 
  Object,Object, Object, recordsTotal: 28, recordsFiltered: 28, draw: 1]
```

the probelm is pagination don't work ,data table shows all data in one page,and when I click on paging button did no action.

Comment: You made error here: `conole.log`

Answer (score 10):

Returned JSON format should be:

```
{
    data: [{Object},{Object},{Object},{Object}…]
    draw: "1"
    recordsFiltered: 91
    recordsTotal: 91
}
```

You can get a complete tutorial from here about [Datatables server-side paging, sorting and filtering in angularjs](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/01/datatables-server-side-paging-sorting-filtering-angularjs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.dataSrc` and use this option:

```
.withDataProp(function(json) {
  console.log(json);
  json.recordsTotal = json.response.total;
  json.recordsFiltered = json.response.total;
  json.draw = 1;
  return json.response.data;
})
```

Change json.response according your object.

Answer (score 0):

```
The return data must be list of object ["data"]=[{name:john,id:1},{name:jason,id:2}].

Try
  .withOption('ajax', {
                  dataSrc: function(data) {                 
                   return data.data;
                     }
                  })
Else,
       .withOption('ajax', {
                  "dataSrc": "data"
                  }
```